# Showing that $\{(x,x):x\in [0,1]\}$ is in $\cal{B}([0,1])\otimes\cal{B}([0,1])$

Tags: measure-theory

I am having a hard time showing that $\{(x,x):x\in [0,1]\}$ is in $\cal{B}([0,1])\otimes\cal{B}([0,1])$.

${\cal{B}}([0,1]) = \{[0,1]\cap B: B \in \cal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably $\mathcal B([0,1]) \otimes \mathcal B([0,1])$ means the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the form $A \times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are Borel subsets of $[0,1]$.

Hint: For example, you might look at sets of the form 
$$\bigcup_{j=1}^n \left( \left[ \frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right] \times  \left[\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right]\right)$$